# ARM LDR instruction on PC register

Tags: assembly, arm, patch, monkeypatching

Here how I understand the story:

- PC register holds pointer to next instruction
- LDR instruction is loading the value of second operand into first operand
  (for example)

  ```
  LDR r0, [pc, 0x5678]
  ```

  is equivalent to this "C code"

  ```
  r0 = *(pc + 0x5678)
  ```

  It's pointer dereferencing with base offset.

And my question:

I found this code

```
LDR PC, [PC,-4]
```

It's commented like monkey patching, etc..

How I understand this code

```
pc = *(pc - 4)
```

I this case "pc" register will dereference the address of previous instruction and will contain the "machine code" of instruction (not the address of instruction),
and program will jump to that invalid address to continue execution, and probably we will get "Segmentation Fault".
So what I'm missing or not understanding?

The thing that makes me to think is the brackets of second operand in LDR instruction.
As I know on x86 architecture brackets are already dereferencing the pointer, but I can't understand the meaning in ARM architecture.

```
mov r1, 0x5678
add r1, pc
mov r0, [r1]
```

is this code equivalent to?

```
LDR r0, [pc, 0x5678]
```

Comment: re the edit: `mov` cannot take a memory operand (ARM is a load-store architecture), so that code is invalid as is - if the third instruction was `ldr r0, [r1]` it would be equivalent. `ldr r0, [pc, 0x5678]` can't be encoded as a single instruction as the immediate is too big (i.e. it can't be represented by an 8-bit value rotated by an even number of bits).

Comment: Notlikethat thanks, it was my problem

Comment: Doesn't PC depend on if the system is 32 or 64-bits?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quoting from section 4.9.4 of the *ARM Instruction Set* document (ARM DDI 0029E):

> When using `R15` as the base register you must remember it contains an address 8 bytes on
>   from the address of the current instruction.

So that instruction will load the word located 4 bytes *after* the current instruction, which hopefully contains a valid address.

Comment: The brackets [] are not already dereferencing pc - 4 address ?

Comment: `LDR PC,[PC, -4]` means load a word from the address formed by the current `PC` (`R15`) minus 4 and put that value in `PC`. Since `PC` is 8 bytes ahead of the current instruction you'll be loading from `current_instruction_address+8-4 == current_instruction_address+4`

Comment: Thanks, but one more thing [PC, -4] what does it do ? "pc - 4" or *(pc - 4) ?

Comment: That would be the latter.

Comment: in that case LDR PC, [PC,-4] will equivalent to this code pc = **((pc - 4)), or my misunderstanding is that LDR is not dereferencing the pointer?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting that extra indirection from(?). What you're doing is `PC = *(PC - 4);` (with the small quirk regarding the value of `PC` on the right-hand side that I've explained in my answer).

Comment: ah, thanks. My problem was LDR instruction. I was thinking that LDR is dereferencing the second operand before assigning, but turned out that it's making simple assignment without dereferencing, the dereference is done by brackets :)

Comment: Is the program counter (PC) always 8 bytes on from the current location?  I see 4 bytes on when the program counter is 32-bits.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @mrbean Without more details it's impossible to give a definitive answer. My first guess would be that you're in Thumb mode, in which case you'd get the address of the instruction + 4 (with bit 0 cleared) when using R15 as an operand.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [a quirk of the ARM architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091566/understanding-the-nature-of-arm-pc-register), `LDR PC, [PC,-4]` <strike>is a branch to the *following* instruction (assuming we're talking ARM, not Thumb here), thus under normal circumstances it has no effect (other than performance). The point is, by putting that instruction at the start of a function it's then really simple for the code to patch itself at runtime by rewriting the bottom 12 bits of the `LDR` instruction to change the offset, thus redirecting that function somewhere else.</strike> branching to an address stored in memory in the word immediately following the instruction. Herp derp, I got `ADR` and `LDR` confused there - the above would be true if it were `ADR`, but this case is even more straightforward.

Now that I've unconfused myself it's just a simple function call trampoline. The function address will be stored as a data word immediately following the `LDR` instruction (presumably set to some initial value by the linker) and can simply be rewritten as data at runtime to redirect the branch, without needing to resort to self-modifying code.

Comment: Notlikethat, branch to the current instruction is not the SUB PC, #-4 ?