# ARMv7a BL instruction, calculate target address

Tags: assembly, arm

I try to understand how the target address is calculated in a BL instruction ARMv7a.

I created a simple example program and compiled and linked it. The object file (elf) has the following instructions.

```
...
  14:   e3400000    movt    r0, #0
  18:   eb00000f    bl  5c <test>
  1c:   e50b0008    str r0, [fp, #-8]
...

0000005c <test>:
  5c:   e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
  60:   e28db000    add fp, sp, #0
```

If I understand BL correct, I should get 5c as target address.

From the reference manual I found the following description:

```
imm32 = SignExtend(imm24:'00', 32);
targetAddress = PC + imm32;
```

Where imm24 are the 24 right bits of the instruction. In my case 0x000000f.

If I calculate the target address this way, I don't get 5c though.

```
// PC = 0x18 (where we find the BL instruction)
uint32_t imm24 = 0x00000f;
uint32_t imm32 = imm24 << 2;
// imm32 = 0x3c
uint32_t targetAddress = PC + imm32;
// targetAddress = 0x18 + 0x3c = 0x54
```

Do I miss something?

I used a arm-none-eabi crosscompiler with the following flags:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -O0 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a7 -marm
```

Comment: You maybe missed the bit about [what's actually in the PC register](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24091566/3156750)...

Comment: What, people exist who read manuals and can ask a question properly? :-O

Comment: @Jester What do you not like about the question? I'm new to ARM and assembly, and even though I'm reading the manual it can happen I miss something.

Comment: That was a compliment and you got a +1 for it ... sorry if it wasn't clear. It doesn't happen too often in the `assembly` tag that people read the manuals and come here asking if something is unclear, show what they did and ask a question properly. Crap gets tons of upvotes and you only got one. Life is not fair.

Comment: Maybe I should read comments better. lol. I tend to ask weird questions sometimes though. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the ARM ARM (document number DDI 0100E):

> The branch target address is calculated by:
>
> 1. Sign-extending the 24-bit signed (two's complement) immediate to 32 bits.
> 2. Shifting the result left two bits.
> 3. Adding this to the contents of the PC, **which contains the address of the branch instruction plus 8.**

As for why this is, see *2.7.4 Prefetching and self-modifying code* in the same document.