# Why in this case the offset relative to "pc" is 0x14, not 0x1C or 0x18?

Tags: assembly, arm, elf, program-counter, relative-addressing

I'm referring to the 2nd instruction in this example:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/ELF_Executable_and_Linkable_Format_diagram_by_Ange_Albertini.png

I.e. `add r1, pc, #20`, while in the hex code it's `14(<- this is what I'm talking about) 10 8F E2`.

Note that the code/text section is located at 0x60. The (2nd) instruction in question is at 0x64. The string that it refers to is at 0x80 (see the "STRINGS" section).

I am not familiar with how `pc` is moved (e.g. before-vs-after instruction is being carried out; always move by instruction length vs. read multiple instructions at the same time).  And I'm guessing that this is where my confusion came from.

In my understanding, `pc` is either at 0x64 (read one instruction, execute, move pc) or 0x68 (read one instruction, move pc, execute). So, in order to refer to the tetx at 0x80, the added value should be 0x1C and 0x18, respectively.

The actual value added is 0x14 (see the hex code in the same example), which seems to say that `pc` should be at 0x6C (after the 3rd instruction) when the 2nd instruction is being executed.

This doesn't make sense to me. What did I miss?

Comment: In ARM mode (Thumb2 is different), the program-counter reads as 2 instructions ahead of the current, unlike on most other ISAs.  [Why does the ARM PC register point to the instruction after the next one to be executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24091566) . It's somewhat arbitrary exactly how PC-relative addressing works on any given ISA; you always have to check the manuals or check an example.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes Cordes. Didn't know that this is ISA-specific. This is good learning.

Comment: BTW, why the downvote on the question though? Unless the person who asks this question (me in this case) already know the answer or the key info in this answer (i.e. the fact that this is ISA-specific; the program is compiled for ARM and this fact matters to the question), the person won't be able to search for and find the "duped" question. Also, the person who ask needed to also assume that they were correct in their read about both the assembly code, the PC, and how the relative address works correctly in the first place, which shouldn't be an assumption for anyone who is new in this area.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I'd guess someone felt it was lack of research effort since searching on `ARM PC-relative addressing` should have found some details about how it works on ARM.  Everything about asm / machine code is potentially ISA-specific.  Or maybe that it was a bit hard to follow exactly what the question was asking; I know it took me some time to figure out that you were asking why that numeric value, rather than something else about how PC changes e.g. on branches. Also, it's asking about code that's only in an off-site image, but you did quote the actual insn so that's kind of ok.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. Yeah as a novice person in this area, I think my first difficult was actually how to ask this question / what question to ask. That probably led to the possibly confusing framing of the question, as you suggested.